# Macro runs different when stepped through

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a range of cells and paste it on an email as image, I came across a code that does that (it makes a chart and the image is pasted there, then saved as an image), when I run it with breaks it works fine, but without them it saves the image with a black space at the bottom.
Heres the code

```vb
Sub SaveImage()

Dim tmp As Variant, str As String, h As Double, w As Double

Dim P3 As Worksheet
Dim Logo As Object

Dim OA, OM As Object
Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OM = OA.CREATEITEM(0)

Set P3 = Worksheets("Draft")

Set Logo = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 1")

    Const dw As Double = 1186.56
    Const dh As Double = 755.28
    Logo.Copy
    Dim sImgName As String
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    
    w = Logo.Width
    h = Logo.Height
    str = "C:\Users\fn031094\Desktop\Screenshot.png"
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set tmp = Charts.Add
    On Error Resume Next
    With tmp
        .PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperExecutive
        .Width = w
        .Height = h
        .PageSetup.TopMargin = IIf(w > dw, dh - dw * h / w, dh - h) + 28
        .PageSetup.BottomMargin = 0
        .PageSetup.RightMargin = IIf(h > dh, dw - dh * w / h, dw - w) + 36
        .PageSetup.LeftMargin = 0
        .PageSetup.HeaderMargin = 0
        .PageSetup.FooterMargin = 0
        .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        DoEvents
        .Paste
        DoEvents
        .Export Filename:=str, Filtername:="png"
        .Delete
    End With
just running the macro i get this
```

When i step through the page set up i get the image like i want it, but

[image]

I dont want that blank space at the bottom
Can someone help me fix it or give another way to send the image? Thanks

Comment: So if you don't want a blank space, what is it you do want there?

Comment: I just want the image, i dont want any blank space around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, your problem is the line

```
Set Logo = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 1")
```

ThisWorkbook is the workbook containing the macro, not the active one.

Please avoid references to an ActiveSheet or ActiveWorkbook in Macros dealing with more than one sheet or book.

Define at the beginning variables and assign the active item to it. Refer then only to your variable.

E.g.:

```
Dim CurSheet as worksheet
…
Set CurSheet=ActiveSheet 
…
Set Logo=CurSheet.Pictures("Picture 1")
```